How to pass a literal value of a variable to an action?
I have an action inside a loop.
        int count = 0;
        foreach(OMD i in settings) 
        {
            if (i.type == OMDSetting.toggle) {
                Components.Register(toggle, EventTriggerType.PointerClick, () => OnToggleUp(toggle, count));
                y -= 60;
            }
            count++;
        }

And when I proc the action.
    public static void OnToggleUp(GameObject toggle, int index)
    {
        OMD s = settings[index];
        s.b = toggle.GetComponent<Toggle>().isOn;
        settings[index] = s;
    }

Problem is that the count variable that gets sent with the action never gives the correct index.  It always sends the value of whatever it is when the loop finishes.
Does C# have any way to get around this?

Make a local copy of count and capture that, as shown in How to tell a lambda function to capture a copy instead of a reference in C#? and Captured variable in a loop in C#.  In fact I believe your question is a duplicate.

@dbc - solution was so easy.  thank you man
